# Mastermind Solver Implementation Issues

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management

I'm writing in C++ an mastermind solver, with a-z possible letters, and the length of the string is to be inserted by the user - and should not be bound, given that we can hold a string of that size in memory. All of this, without using STD containers such as vector, etc. Also, without guessing guesses that are incorrect given the previously given feedbacks.

I wrote a dumbed-down version of Knuth's algorithm: 
For each feedback we get back after a guess, we eliminate all other possibilities that if they were the actual code, they would not result this feedback. Unlike Knuth's, I'm not using minmax after that, I'm just eliminating from the group of possible guesses those that can't possibly be correct, based on feedbacks.

I implemented this in two ways:

1. Holding a boolean table of size 26^Length, which will denote if a guess X is still possible. Then at each getPossibleGuess() call we would return the string corresponding to the first valid cell (cell number 0 is aaa...a, cell 2 is aaaa...ab etc).
   And when receiving a feedback we iterate over the table and setting cells to 'false' if the string they represent would not give the same feedback if they were the actual code.

Problem with this: Array size. 26^Length can get pretty big, and even a short length like 20 gives us a number not even unsigned long long can handle. So we can't satisfy the requirement for unbound length.

Second implementation:

2. Holding a class member which is the current string. When given a feedback, store that feedback. When asked for a possible guess, increment the current string (aaa...a into aaa..ab, aaa...az into aaaa...aba etc) and check if it complies with all the previously stored feedbacks. If so, return it. If not, increment and continue to search.

Problem with this: This can deal with as long a string as we want, but it is very very very slow. very.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction on how to solve these issues.

Thank you!

Comment: *"All of this, without using STD containers such as vector, etc."* You say this like it's a good thing.

Comment: Not at all. I was sort of ranting :)

Comment: Have you verified that you are really fighting with an *implementation problem*, and not with a *conceptual problem*? Solving mastermind with 26^20 possible combinations just sounds like it *must* be computing intensive, unless you find some really clever optimizations.

Comment: You can store up to 32 boolean values in a single integer... set a bit to 0 if the corresponding letter is still possible, or set it to 1 if it the letter has been ruled out. Then you only need an array of int[length] to keep track of all your possibilities.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Well, in a single 32-bit integer. More generally, you can store N boolean values in an N-bit integer. (Two 16-bit integers are just as good if no padding is necessary, for example.)

Comment: @cdhowie. Of course. I was just trying to illustrate that using a 32 bit `unsigned int` would effectively create a bitfield big enough to contain every letter possibility.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Right. Though `unsigned int` is only guaranteed to be at least 16 bits. In this case I'd be more inclined to use `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>` since they both use the storage mechanism you propose, but hide this detail making the rest of the code cleaner.

Comment: @cdhowie I was going to suggest the exact same thing, but the Question asker has already mentioned they can't use std containers

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments I propose that you have an array of `unsigned longs` to track the possiblities. An `unsigned int` will also suffice on many platforms as long as `sizeof(int)` is more than 26 bits.

Each `unsigned long` in the array represents the set of possible letters that can be played at the corresponding position.

Examining the bits of the `long`:

```
00000000000000000000000000010101
      ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

In this example the value is set to 21 which would correspond to 'A', 'C', and 'E' being already ruled as unplayable and all the other letters still being in contention.

You could use constants to track the "bit value" of each letter. (An enum won't work if `sizeof(enum value)` is less than 26 bits).

```
const unsigned long A = 1 << 0;  // ==1  or 00000000000000001
const unsigned long B = 1 << 1;  // ==2  or 00000000000000010
const unsigned long C = 1 << 2;  // ==4  or 00000000000000100
const unsigned long D = 1 << 3;  // ==8  or 00000000000001000
const unsigned long E = 1 << 4;  // ==16 or 00000000000010000
// etc ...
```

You then create an array with one unsigned long for each position where a letter can be placed:

```
unsigned long possibilities [20] = {};
```

Then to rule out a letter you can bitwise OR `|` the constant letter value with the unsigned long in the correct position in the array. So for example, to rule out the letter 'D' at location 4, you could call:

```
possibilities[3] |= D; // rules out d by flipping the 'D' bit to 1.
```

To reset at the end of the game simply reset all values in your possibilities array back to 0.

To determine if a letter is still playable the following code using bitwise AND `&` would work:

```
if( (possibilities[3] & D) == D )
{
    // D's bit is set to 1 therefore D has been ruled out
}
else
{
    // D's bit is set to 0 therefore D is still a possibility
}
```

Note that this can also be accomplished (more elegantly) using std containers such as [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

You can encapsulate all this in a nice `class` so that the mucking around with bits is shielded wholly from any client code.

Answer (score 0):

1) Knuth's algorithm only works for small puzzle sets, e.g. 6 colors, 4 locations for a total of 6<sup>4</sup> = 1296 possible answers. Large puzzle sets won't fit into memory, and take too long to analyze with minmax.

2) The counting algorithm will take forever since, for example, 26<sup>20</sup> = 2<sup>94</sup>. Forget about verifying whether a given solution is consistent with the feedback, just a simple loop that counts to 2<sup>94</sup> would take too long.

3) So you need a whole different approach. The best approach is one that's simple for a computer to implement (although boring and tedious for a human player).

Start with a guess that's all `a`s, the feedback tells you how many `a`s are in the answer.  Repeat for `b` through `z`. Now you know how many of each letter you need.

Next you need to determine the correct locations for the letter `a`. So make a guess that has one `a` and all the rest `b`. The feedback for that guess will be 1 of 3 different possibilities. Assuming that the number of `b`s is known to be `B`, then the feedback will be

```
    1 white and B-1 black, if the 'a' is where a 'b' should be.
    1 white and B   black, if the 'a' is where a 'c' thru 'z' should be.
    0 white and B+1 black, if the 'a' is in one of the correct locations.
```

After guessing with a single `a` at each position, you will know exactly where all of the `a`s and `b`s go. From then on, you can always guess with the `a`s and `b`s in the correct locations. In the unknown positions, put one `c` and the rest `d`s ...

Comment: Thank you, that would be a good solution. However, it is specified that we may not guess guesses that are incorrect given the previous feedbacks.